# Probability question regarding $P(a < X < b)$ formula

Tags: probability

We are tossing the coin $4000$ times. $X$ is the number of heads.
$$P(3000 < X < k) = 0.7$$
Need to find $k$. ($k$ could be less than $3000$) Im trying to use Laplace integral theorem, but always getting result bigger than $1$ and not $0.7$

Comment: Please read tag excerpts before applying a tag. See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17544/about-probability-theory-tag) related meta discussion. [tag:probability-theory] has nothing to do with computing a specific probability and [tag:laplace-transform] has nothing to do with the [De Moivre-Laplace theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem).

Comment: With a fair coin, $P(3000<X<k)<P(2000<X)=\frac12$